# Entity Framework 5 SaveChanges does not save data to all related tables

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I am updating an Entity Framerwork 4.1 / MVC 3 to Entity Framework 5.0 / MVC 4 using Visual Studio 2012. The database is SQL Server 2005. Below is an image of the database tables and their relationships. Each table has a primary key. The primary keys in the auxillary tables are Identity. Tables are related by FormId.

[image: Database Tables]

When I **Update from Database**, EF imports the tables and their relationships.

Using EF 4.1 I was able to write the following code that successfully saved (inserted) in all four tables with one SaveChanges() call. I created a new GUID programmatically and added nsForm to the other three tables. When SaveChanges() was executed, EF 4 saved NSForm first and applied the FormId to the other three tables automatically as it saved each of them.

```
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        Guid formGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        bool success = false;

            using (var context = new NSAFormsEntities())
            {
                NSAFormsEDM.NSForm nsForm = new NSAFormsEDM.NSForm();
                SpeakerphoneForm speakerphoneForm = new SpeakerphoneForm();
                NSAFormsEDM.Requestor requestor = new NSAFormsEDM.Requestor();
                NSAFormsEDM.Authorizer authorizer = new NSAFormsEDM.Authorizer();

                nsForm.FormGuid = formGuid;
                nsForm.Form = "Speakerphone";
                nsForm.CreateDate = currentDateTime;
                nsForm.ModifiedBy = currentUser;

                #region Speakerphone
                speakerphoneForm.FormGuid = formGuid;
                speakerphoneForm.ServiceDate = speakerphoneVM.ServiceDate;
                speakerphoneForm.LocationId = speakerphoneVM.LocationId;
                speakerphoneForm.CreateDate = currentDateTime;
                speakerphoneForm.CreatedBy = currentUser;
                speakerphoneForm.NSForm = nsForm;
                #endregion

                #region Requestor
                requestor.FormGuid = formGuid;
                requestor.NetworkId = currentUser;
                requestor.CreateDate = currentDateTime;
                requestor.CreatedBy = currentUser;
                requestor.NSForm = nsForm;
                #endregion

                #region Authorizer
                authorizer.FormGuid = formGuid;
                authorizer.NetworkId = authorizerVM.NetworkId;
                authorizer.CreateDate = currentDateTime;
                authorizer.CreatedBy = currentUser;
                authorizer.NSForm = nsForm;
                #endregion

                context.NSForms.Add(nsForm);
                context.SaveChanges();
                success = true;
            }
```

Now, using EF 5.0 only data in NSForm is inserted. Apparantly, EF 5 no longer propogates the FormId key, as expressed in the table relationships, to the three auxillary tables

Questions: How should code using EF 5 be written in order to insert data into all of the tables with one SaveChanges() call?

Thanks,

Arnold

Comment: If things worked in 4.1 they should continue to work in EF5. From what I see you set references to nsForm everywhere and then just add nsForm - this seems to be unidirectional. Show your classes to better understand what's happening there. if you need a quick fix you can manually add the entities you created to the context before saving changes.

Comment: Thanks for posting Pawel. After digging into this more I have discovered that you are correct. Most things in EF5 work as they did in EF4.1. However, I have found at least one difference. The code sample will work in EF5 if I add one more line for each entity save. E.g. context.SpeakerphoneForms.Add(speakerphoneForm); placed after: speakerphoneForm.NSForm = nsForm; What was implicit in EF4.1 now must be explicit in EF5.